# Embed a file in robotframework report or log?

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to embed a file in an robotframework log or report?

For example, say a particular test runs a shell command and creates an output file.  Can I attach that file to the log so that I can open that file later?

I've seen screenshots attached as part of the selenium integration, so it seems like that capability exists at some level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you log something that looks like a hyperlink, robot will turn it in to a hyperlink. For example, if "data.txt" is in the same folder as the log file you can do something like this:

```
| | log | file://data.txt
```

You can also create your own hyperlink with the optional `html=True` argument to log:

```
| | log | <a href="file://path/to/file">test data file</a> | html=True
```