# how to embed a file in the robot framework log file

Tags: python, robotframework

I use the following keyword to embed a test file to the robot framework log file but it is not working. The "data.txt" file is placed in the same folder as the log file.

```
Log     file://data.txt
```

But it gives the following error log message

```
The webpage at file://data.txt/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Any help is appreciated on this issue?

Comment: This was already answered here by Bryan Oakley, [Embed a file in robotframework report or log?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25922499/17663093)

Answer (score 0):

If you log something that looks like a hyperlink, robot will turn it in to a hyperlink. For example, if "data.txt" is in the same folder as the log file you can do something like this:

```
| | log | file://data.txt
```

You can also create your own hyperlink with the optional html=True argument to log:

```
| | log | <a href="file://path/to/file">test data file</a> | html=True
```